# MVC3 Editor Template for ID's like SSN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and am finding the options for displaying something like an SSN to be a bit much.

I have a need to display various types of unique ID's, but the UI calls for the parts of them to be split out into different text boxes. For example, a Social Security Number with the first three digits in a text box, the next two digits in another text box and so on. I used jQuery auto-tab plugin to help the user quickly enter the data.

With regard to hooking this up to MVC3, it seems like I should use an Editor Template like this and use the [UIHint("ssn")] along with @Html.EditorFor:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBox("", Model != null ? Model.Substring(0, 2) : "")
@Html.TextBox("", Model != null ? Model.Substring(2, 5) : "")
@Html.TextBox("", Model != null ? Model.Substring(5, 3) : "")
```

Is this the best way to be going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the best way to be going about this?

Using a custom editor template to split the SSN into 3 textboxes is definitely good but I am afraid it is only the first part (it is the way to present the view model inside the view).

But I guess that since you are presenting those values in textboxes you will expect the user to enter some values into these textboxes. And that you will probably want to fetch those values back into the SSN property of your view model when the user submits the form. This will be the second part. You might need a custom model binder to handle this. Hansleman [blogged with an example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx).

Comment: And so that implies that I need an SSN model class right? So just so I make sure I understand this correctly, in order to capture an SSN in three input text boxes instead of one, I have to create an SSN class with three string fields, create an SSN model binder, create a custom attribute so I can decorate the class that has SSN as a property, and create custom Editor and Display Templates...? I am kind of surprised how much has to be done for such a simple customization.

Comment: @tnktnk, no, you have a view model containing a single SSN property decorated with the `[UIHint]` attribute to indicate that this property should be rendered with the custom editor template you have defined and which contains the logic you have shown in your question. You could also define a SSN attribute to decorate your SSN property with. See Hansleman's blog post I've linked to in my answer about this second part.

Comment: I would need to make an SSN model because you use a model binder to tell the controller how to bind the model to the view, right?